# Cloud run connection to postgres intermittently doesn't work on first attempt

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-sql, prisma, google-cloud-run, bullmq

We have 6 cloud run containers, all running with 2GiB of memory, 1 CPU, and 1 minimum instance. All of them have very similar dockerfiles that essentially start up simple express services.

We use a Postgres database running on Cloud SQL with 2 vCPUs, 8GB memory that all 6 cloud run containers have access to.

We use Prisma (https://github.com/prisma/prisma) to access the database.

One of our cloud run containers is used for us to process simple jobs on demand using BullMQ (a redis-based queue). In that container that, the infra is essentially the same as the others; however, occasionally, prisma is unable to reach our database. This generally only happens on the first attempt to connect to the database after a restart, but the amount of time after that restart can be any amount (even many hours). There is almost no activity on the other cloud run containers as well so there is only a very light volume of usage of the database at any given time.

The exact error message we see is `Timed out fetching a new connection from the connection pool. More info: http://pris.ly/d/connection-pool (Current connection pool timeout: 10, connection limit: 5)` Since this is the first connection, it means that there are definitely not a lack of connections available in the pool. Whenever everything is working, connections are obtained very fast (milliseconds). On failures, it takes the full 10 seconds and then times out.

We've tried many ways of solving this including:

1. Bumping prisma's timeout to 20 seconds and its connection limit to 10 connections. This still causes failures
2. Adding retries on the connection. We added 3 and sometimes it would still fail after 3 attempts. Other times it would only fail 0-2 times. However, if we ever manually retried a 4th time, it worked.
3. Bumping prisma's timeout to infinite. So far we haven't seen any failures when doing that but it may just be low volume of attempts - and all the connections still happened in milliseconds.

I can't imagine that this issue is caused by Prisma given:

1. its only happening on this one cloud run container. we use the same prisma configuration (though different connection pools) in all the containers
2. its happening on both our staging and production instances on the same jobs cloud run container.
   So this feels like it has something to do with the setup of this cloud run instance.

Attempts at reproduction:

1. wait many hrs with 0 requests and retry. haven't been able to repro
2. manually deploy a new cloud run instance and try after that one is taking all the traffic as the first request. haven't been able to repro (even though most, if not all, of the failures have been on the first request)

More info exists on the prisma page question I asked: https://github.com/prisma/prisma/discussions/22252

Comment: How are you connecting to your Cloud SQL instance? Public IP, private IP? Built-in Cloud SQL integration? Or direct?

Comment: setting the prisma connection url with the private ip of the cloud sql instance (along with username/password/port/etc)

Comment: I don't know much about Prisma's internal connection pool functionality, but wonder if you've tried enabling "Always On CPU"? The idea being the CPU throttling is breaking the connection pool and causing this behavior.

Comment: @enocom I'm not sure if the prisma connection pool matters a ton here. since its usually the first connection, its just prisma attempting to establish a connection with our database which is timing out. I can set up the always on setting but wouldn't that be affecting all the containers then?

Comment: Does the db server's logfile show anything while this going on?

Comment: I see 3 errors at the general time of the latest failure: `could not accept SSL connection: EOF detected`, `could not accept SSL connection: Connection reset by peer`, and `could not receive data from client: Connection reset by peer`. The last one actually shows up many times at other points in time as well so it may be benign?

Comment: Though I'm not sure that I can find those errors during the other failures so it may just be a coincidence

Comment: The other thing worth adding to your question is the code showing how you're initializing your connection. If you're doing the work outside of a request context, you're bound to have unusual behavior, as the CPU is only allocated while serving the request.

Comment: +1 to @enocom comment above. If you are initializing the connection pool as a global variable outside of the request context than you will see timeouts as CPU is only allocated during request contexts unless you set CPU to "Always on".

Comment: The solution would be to lazy init the connection pool, tips on lazy init for Cloud Run can be found here: https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/samples/cloudrun-tips-global-lazy#cloudrun_tips_global_lazy-nodejs

Comment: Got it, we'll give that a try and I'll report back. Thanks for the suggestions

Comment: Your solution is either to enable Always on CPU or contact the Prisma team to fix their code to handle connection errors. When a Cloud Run instance is not processing requests, it receives no CPU time. That will cause TCP connection problems which you are seeing in the logs. Their code is not handling those issues.

Comment: so far so good with the Always on CPU change. What I'm surprised about is that its not impacting my other cloud run services given they have essentially the same infra.